# crystal command fails with ld: library not found for -lgc

Tags: macos, crystal-lang

When trying to run the program `hello` from https://github.com/askn/crystal-by-example, I get the following output

```
$ crystal hello.cr
ld: library not found for -lgc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see . invocation)
Error: execution of command failed with code: 1: `cc "${@}" -o '/Users/senpo/.cache/crystal/crystal-run-hello.tmp'  -rdynamic  -lpcre -lgc -lpthread /opt/brew/Cellar/crystal-lang/0.24.1_1/src/ext/libcrystal.a -levent -liconv -ldl -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib`
```

I've already tried to

1. `xcode-select --install`
2. `xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
3. Reinstall XCode

but still get the same error. Can anyone help me get my crystal installation right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution in https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/3067. It seems to be a known crystal issue. The solution is to set the environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH` to the library folder of the homebrew installation, in my case `/opt/brew/lib`:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/brew/lib
```

Comment: Same solution with a different path worked for me.   `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/`   Sourced [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1089390/how-to-install-libssl-dev-libffi-dev-on-mac-os?newreg=0849de27be28401ea6864d507e364178)

Answer (score 1):

run it with `run` command

```
crystal run hello.cr
```

or you can build the package and run built code

```
crystal build hello.cr
./hello
```